# WHERE with joined tables

Tags: mysql, join

I basicly have a query similiar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM news
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.newsid = news.id
```

Now let's say, that I want to get all `news` rows which have a tag (row in `tags` table) that's `tags.name` value is "test" and another tag that's `tags.name` value is "test2". 
So basicly, I would like to check for two values in a joined table, if they are both in there, then give back that `news` row.

How would this be possible? Sorry if this has been asked before, I don't really know what kind of keywords I would use in my search for this particular question, since it's quite complicated.

Comment: select * from news where (select count(*) from tags where tags.newsId = news.id and tags.name='test')=1 and (select count(*) from tags where tags.newsId = news.id and tags.name='test2')=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT news.*, COUNT(*) c
FROM news
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.newsid = news.id
WHERE tags.name IN ("test", "test2")
HAVING c = 2
```

I'm assuming the combination of `tags.newsid, tags.name` is unique.

Here's how you do what you asked for in the comment.

```
SELECT news.*, COUNT(*) c
FROM news n
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tags.newsid newsid
    FROM tags
    WHERE tags.name = "test"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT tags.newsid 
    FROM tags
    WHERE tags.name IN ("test2", "test3")
) t
ON t.newsid = n.id
HAVING c = 2
```

Another way to do it is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT news.*
FROM news n
JOIN tags t1 ON n.id = t1.newsid
JOIN tags t2 ON n.id = t2.newsid
WHERE t1.name = "test"
AND t2.name IN ("test2", "test3")
```

This latter method is easier to extrapolate to arbitrary combinations.

Comment: Thanks. I have another issue though... what if it should have tags where it has: ("test" AND ("test2" OR "test3")) ?

Comment: Ah, the last method is perfect for what I want to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  select * from news where 
(select count(*) from tags  where tags.newsId = news.id and tags.name='test')=1 and 
(select count(*) from tags where tags.newsId = news.id and tags.name='test2')=1
```

Comment: works, but I don't think that's good about readability and performance, looks more like a quickfix

Comment: yes, that's not very ellegant, but look at the OP's comment above, it should be able to handle those kind of cases also

Answer (score 0):

Using a subquery to identify the relevant rows in the tag table should give you the results you're seeking.

```
SELECT * FROM news n
INNER JOIN (SELECT newsid FROM tags WHERE tags.name in ('test1', 'test2')) t
ON n.id = t.newsid
```

Comment: Don't use `LEFT JOIN`, it will show news items that don't have either of these tags.

Comment: That's right, thanks. The query has been corrected, although I'm not sure it is exactly what the OP wanted.

Comment: I think the concensus is that he wants news items that have _both_ tags, your query finds items that have _either_ tag.

Comment: And see his comment to my answer -- I think he has aspirations to arbirtary boolean combinations.

Comment: Right - the problem is that I am using this in a ColdFusion environment, and both "test" and "test2" can have multiple values; imagine that you want to search for news that contains the keyword "html" and/or "css" (the "test" value), and the newsitem must have the tag "development" and/or "web".